# facebook deep link android: "Deep link notification could not be sent due to some errors."

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, deeplink

I am trying to set up Facebook deep linking feature for my Android app. (My end goal is deferred deep linking, but I am even stuck with regular deep linking, so this is my question).

I created a Facebook App and pointed it to my Android app:[image]

I installed FB SDK (the react-native version) and added FB App id in my Android Manifest.xml:

```xml
$ cat android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml 
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Invest Advisor</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1807501069529222</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1807501069529222</string>
</resources>


$ cat android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.investadvisor">

    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

            .....

            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="investadvisor" android:host="open"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I open FB App Ads Helper  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper I see that it detects installs correctly (it shows the date of last install).

But when I try to fire a deep link it says "Deep link notification could not be sent due to some errors":

[image]

Why can that be? I have Facebook on my Android, and I am logged in there, so it looks like all the requirements have been met.

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: @sanjay sadly, i havent

Answer (score 0):

You have to login to facebook app on device with the same account you have a developer account then send a notification. It works

Also check you have enabled the deeplinking for the project in Settings >> Basic

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 hours, I came to know that they gave clear instructions that **the Facebook app should be installed on the device** where you want to send the deep link. I don't have bcoz I was testing in the emulator.

Also, You should be **logged in with the app account which you are using for creating apps** in Meta for developers.

This solved this issue for me. Please read the **DIRECTIONS** in the image.

**NOTE: Also, Enabling the deep link option is removed in the new META APP DASHBOARD. By default, It is enable.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also one possibility if you have multiple emails for your account. you need to log in with the same email otherwise even if it is the same account you cannot receive the notification.